# /bin/bash: Command not found in alpine docker

Tags: bash, docker, jenkins, makefile, alpine-linux

I'm trying to run this `Makefile` in an `alpine` docker.

```
SHELL := /bin/bash

build:
    GOOS=linux go build -o bin/server main.go
```

I have ascertained that both `bash`, `make`, `go` is there by interactively going into the container and checking all commands.

But this command mysteriously fails:

```
+ make build
make: /bin/bash: Command not found
GOOS=linux go build -o bin/server main.go
make: /bin/bash: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:17: build] Error 127
script returned exit code 2
```

I have a real hard time debugging this as it's in a docker and it's `jenkins` that is executing everything.

Comment: We'll need a little more debugging information. How have you ascertained that make is there? Does it have execute permissions? Sometimes bash reports things not found when they are there but it can't run them. Other things to try: `which make`; `file /usr/bin/make` (if that's where it is); `updatedb; locate make`

Comment: @IanGibbs do point me to stuff you think can be useful for debugging. :)

Comment: as for make — I went into the container and checked all the commands one by one

Comment: Also, does it work OK if you run that make command yourself (ie not via jenkins)? I should imagine so.

Comment: oh, I removed the `SHELL`-variable and now it started working. possibly had something to do with `/bin/bash` then.

Comment: strange cause it was for sure present in `/bin/`.

Comment: Was your Makefile edited from a windows host? Check your line endings.

Answer (score 10):

To add `bash` using Alpine Package Keeper (APK) use the follow command:

```
apk update
apk add --no-cache bash
```

Don't forget set `bash` as default shell:

```
apk add --no-cache shadow
chsh -s /bin/bash
exec /bin/bash
```

Comment: You can change explicit `/bin/bash` to `$(which bash)`.

Comment: If you wish see the details about it, run `getent passwd $USER`.

Comment: chsh: PAM: Authentication token manipulation error

Comment: What is shadow?

Answer (score 7):

use the package manager, named apk, this way:

```
% docker run --rm -it alpine /bin/sh
/ #
/ # apk add --no-cache bash
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/5) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.0-r8)
(2/5) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.0-r8)
(3/5) Installing ncurses-libs (6.0-r8)
(4/5) Installing readline (6.3.008-r4)
(5/5) Installing bash (4.3.46-r5)
Executing bash-4.3.46-r5.post-install
Executing busybox-1.25.1-r0.trigger
OK: 12 MiB in 16 packages
/ # which -a bash
/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `/bin/bash` in alpine:

```
$ docker run -i -t alpine
/ # ls /bin/bash
ls: /bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

Note that there is no `make`  or `go` neither. So, either you checked their existence in your host instead of in alpine, or you are not using vanilla alpine.

Comment: OK, well I had specifically installed it with `apk add --no-cache bash`

Comment: Fine. I guess you also installed `make` and `go`. It should work, then. As `make` seems to be there, it is not a matter of using the wrong container. Are you sure you performed all steps in the correct order?

Comment: By the way, the Makefile you show is it really the one you are using? No comment at the end of the `SHELL := /bin/bash` line?