# Error: Cannot find module '/var/apps/frontend/bash'

Tags: node.js, dockerfile

I am trying to setup node 15.3.2 version using docker compose file. I have added all the necessary requirements in dockerfile. But after executing `docker compose up` command, I am facing below error. I tried `docker compose --build` command as well. If any one have any solution please let me know.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:15-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /var/apps/frontend
COPY frontend /var/apps/frontend/
RUN apk update 
RUN apk add alpine-sdk 
RUN apk add --update npm
RUN apk add --update python3 make g++ && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN npm install -g npm@9.9.2
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm rebuild node-sass --force
RUN npm i react@15.3.2 --legacy-peer-deps
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/frontend/Dockerfile
    container_name: ui
    command: bash -c "npm config set package-lock false && npm install && yarn run docker"
    networks: ['ao_platform_network']
    depends_on: ['django']
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      - RAILS_ENV=development
      - RAKE_ENV=development
      - NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./frontend
        target: /var/apps/frontend
```

Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/apps/frontend/bash'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:924:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:769:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Comment: Can [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040369/1278987) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, **`bash`** is not included with **`Alpine Linux`**. So, you need to add this command in Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk update && apk add bash
```

But note that just adding this should be more than enough:

```
RUN apk add bash
```

You may also add **`--no-cache`** option to avoid keeping the downloaded packages in cache:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
```

More details in here:

[How to install bash in Alpine](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/alpine-linux-install-bash-using-apk-command/)

[Bash on alpine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55801955/bash-on-alpine-linux)

[/bin/bash: Command not found in alpine docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860784/bin-bash-command-not-found-in-alpine-docker)